# Datepicker in spinner mode Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

is there any ways to inflate datepicker in spinner mode ? When I use AndroidView I cannot use xml view.I tried to define attribute set but still couldnt manage to get it. When I define in style, I cannot scroll properly.

```
    <style name="DatePickerSpinnerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    </style>

        val customView = DatePicker(ContextAmbient.current, null, R.style.NdDatePickerSpinnerStyle)
        customView.spinnersShown = true //deprecated
        customView.calendarViewShown = false //deprecated
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.White)
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            viewBlock = { customView })
```

Answer (score 0):

try use R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog
Seems work for me.